# Prevent double invocation of recursive function in Common Lisp

Tags: recursion, lisp, common-lisp

I have that Lisp function:

```
(defun F(l)
      (cond
        ((atom l) -1)
        ((>(F(car l))0)(+(car l)(F(car l))(F(cdr l))))
        (t(F(cdr l)))
      )
)
```

and I want to prevent double invocation of recursive function `(F (car l))` in the second line of cond using a lambda function.

I tried that:

```
(defun F(l)
  ((LAMBDA (ff)
         (cond
             ((atom l) -1)
             ((> ff 0)(+(car l) ff (F(cdr l))))
             (t(F(cdr l)))
         )
    ) (F (car l)))
)
```

but I get error :

> CAR: 1 is not a list

at call `(F '(1 2 3 4))`.

Also I'm not sure if that correctly avoids double recursive call.

Comment: Any particular reason you do not want to use [`let`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_let_l.htm)?

Comment: It would be nice if you could format your code in a more traditional Lisp style (indentation, spaces, and paren placement)

Comment: @sds I could use let too, but I'm more familiar with lambda, I'm not sure how to solve that with let.

Answer (score 4):

The reason you are getting this error is that you are calling `(car l)` *always*, even when `l` is, in fact, not a `list`.

To avoid this, only do that when *needed*:

```
(defun F(l)
  (if (atom l) -1
      (let* ((l1 (car l))
             (f1 (F l1))
             (f2 (F (cdr l))))
        (if (plusp f1)
            (+ l1 f1 f2)
            f2))))
```